# Gettext will always use system default locale

Tags: php, windows, apache, gettext

I need to localise a Windows-only PHP web application and I'm evaluating the [gettext extension](http://php.net/gettext) but I'm having the hardest time trying to make it work in my Windows 7 development box. I've used trial and error together with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to overcome the poor and inaccurate documentation and I've managed to make `_()` display strings from the *.po catalogue that corresponds to the computer's default locale (Modern Spanish in my case). **All my attempts to set a different locale are silently ignored.**

I've written a test script with lots of redundant stuff:

```
<dl><?php

define('DIR_LOCALE', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'locale');
bindtextdomain('general', DIR_LOCALE);
bind_textdomain_codeset('general', 'UTF-8');
textdomain('general');

if(!defined('LC_MESSAGES')){
    define('LC_MESSAGES', 5);
}

$pruebas = array(
    'enu',
    'es_ES',
    'en_GB',
    'english-uk',
    'Spanish_Spain.1252',
    'esn',
    'spanish',
    'spanish-modern',
);
foreach($pruebas as $locale){
    putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);

    putenv("LC_MESSAGES=$locale");
    setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, $locale);

    putenv("LANGUAGE=$locale");
    putenv("LANG=$locale");
?>
    <dt><?=htmlspecialchars($locale)?></dt>
    <dd><?=_('codigo_idioma')?></dd>
<?php } ?>
</dl>
```

In my case, `<?=_('codigo_idioma')?>` always prints `es_ES@modern`.

I have PHP/5.4.5 but I'm expecting to get it working in any reasonably up-to-date server our customers own.

I've read lots of vague references about the need to install locales even on Windows but no exact details. **What can the problem be?**

<sup>*(I'm aware that the common advice is to dump gettext and use any other library.)*</sup>

---

**Further testing:**

My code run flawlessly as-is in another two computers: 32-bit Windows Vista and 32-bit Windows 7 32-bit. It fails in my computer (64-bit Windows 7) and another one (32-bit Windows Server 2003)

- Apache version seems irrelevant (it also happens with the command-line interpreter).
- PHP version seems irrelevant (also tried latest 32-bit PHP/5.5.5 in my PC).
- My `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls]` registry tree is identical to the other Seven box.

**Edit:** While testing on the command-line, I've discovered that setting the `LANG` environment variable before running the PHP script finally changes the language:

```
C:\>set LANG=en_GB
C:\>php C:\test\gettext.php
```

This definitively proves that my computer has the correct assets but also makes me wonder why PHP claims that `putenv()` works and then ignores it:

```
var_dump( getenv('LANG'), putenv('LANG=en_GB'), getenv('LANG') );
```

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
string(5) "en_GB"
```

Even this doesn't have any effect:

```
$_ENV['LANG'] = 'en_GB';
$_SERVER['LANG'] = 'en_GB';
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I'm having the same problem (64-bit Win 8.1). As you mentioned, if I use "set LANG" before running the script it works. I need to make it work through Apache.

Comment: @fromvega Not at all. The same gettext-enabled code works in some Windows computers and doesn't work in some other ones—that's the only thing I know so far.

Comment: Hi there. I know that's has been a while but just hit this post and remebered a long time ago I have a similar problem with other kind of enviroment variable. Have you tried to add the enviroment variable through Apache modules? Like it is said here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html

Comment: @JorgeCampos I suppose you're proposing a workaround. I guess I could figure out a way to move my language selection logic from PHP sessions to Apache (maybe using cookies) but I think I should mention I've already solved that with a [pure PHP class that reads gettext catalogues](https://launchpad.net/php-gettext) and serves as fallback when gettext refuses to work property. Such class is not under active development and it probably lacks some advanced features but it's been working well so far.

Comment: Yeah its kind of a work around. When I face such a problem I realize that the PHP in that time was having having problems because it was not the owner of the process execution (meaning on the OS) so I figure that if I set the variable on the process that call it, it would work and it worked at the time. But glad to know that you already figured it out. So, you should post your solution as an answer. As a friend of mine use to say: The best solution is the one you can do at least until someone came with another one better. :) Cheers

Comment: I assume you know that 64bit PHP is still considered **Experimental** [See the PHP web site](http://windows.php.net/qa/) look to the bottom of the left hand column. Could this have anything to do with your problem?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Probably not, because I'm using a 32-bit stack and I can also reproduce the issue on a 32-bit Windows 8 virtual machine. So far, I'm wondering if it has to do with the VC build... but I've basically lost hope :)

Comment: My mistake, I thought you were using a 64bit PHP on the 64bit windows. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an [issue](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66265) that's been acknowledged and [partially fixed](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/56fac96bec882ac59a7fc298c98407bf4a17629d) by the PHP team.

It's a fairly technical thing, apparently related to the way environment variables (on which gettext heavily depends) are handled by the underlying platform. Also, something has changed in the Visual C Runtime libraries from VC9 to VC11 that affects all this.

To sum up:

- Non thread-safe builds have been fixed in the source tree on 21<sup>st</sup> Nov. 2014.
- Thread-safe builds (e.g. Apache module) haven't and there isn't a clear solution in sight.

Comment: @ChrisChilvers - You're right, I've edited the answer.

Comment: I have the same issue. Sho, what's now? What can I do if I want to use PHP 7.1 with Apache 2.4 and gettext? Any idea?

Comment: @BuzoganyLaszlo Alternatives: 1) Use a build that is unaffected 2) Drop gettext in favour of some other library 3) Fix the issue yourself ;-)

Comment: After days of research I finally get a working version with Apache 2.4 x64 VC14 + FCGID + PHP 7.1 NTS x64 VC14.

Comment: @BuzoganyLaszlo Thanks for your report. That agrees with what we know so far: non-thread safe builds were fixed on late 2014.

Answer (score 3):

The key is to **use a Non Thread Safe (=NTS) version of PHP**.

Unfortunatelly Windows and PHP does not handle well the environments for threaded processes, so the putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale); command does not work.

Finally I end up with Apache 2.4 + FCGID + PHP 7.1 NTS, which works well now on Windows 7, and it is a non thread safe installation.

A step by step instruction on how to install a such system is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UXrJPrGaPB0

I have used the VC14 and x64 version for all components (VC is abbreviation for "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable"). For this I first installed VC14, downloaded from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem with PHP 5.6.30 VC11 Theard Safe on Windows 10. Workaround found and fix this issue [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66265) by sirio3mil.

Apparently PHP with TS can access only Locale language folder. So when setlocale and putenv function is call with another language than system's one, folder with .mo and .po cannot be read.

Workaround is to have only one language folder with system language and multiple pairs of .mo/.po files for each translated languages. Domain will be set with wanted language.

Example with Swiss French, German and Italian:

### Folder structure

> \Locale\fr_CH\LC_MESSAGES
>
> - fr_CH.mo + fr_CH.po // system language
> - de_CH.mo + de_CH.po
> - it_CH.mo + it_CH.po

### Code

```
$lang = 'fr_CH' or 'de_CH' or 'it_CH'

bindtextdomain($lang, '.\Locale');
textdomain($lang);
bind_textdomain_codeset($lang, 'UTF-8');
setlocale (LC_ALL, $lang);
putenv('LC_ALL=' . $lang);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: Done! I've copy my explanation instead of link :-)

Comment: This workaround really works, thank you. Even if all my mo/po files now locate in ru_RU folder, which is weird and ugly.

But this code will not work after deploy on Unix system, as Unix will still try to search for en_GB/ and zh_CN/ folders (in my case). So, as another small workaround/fix I have created symlinks on Unix. Both symlinks (en_GB and zh_CN) look to ru_RU folder. Now works on Unix too with this folders structure and this code.

Answer (score 1):

First problem: setlocale()

To make this work, you need to set a valid locale. On windows, setlocale() won't work as expected. You need to set an environment variable, like this:

```
// putenv("LANG=$lang");  <- WRONG!
putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
```

Second problem: locale names.

Windows locale names are different from Linux. Try with 'ita', 'eng', 'deu', 'ger', 'esp'.
You can get a complete list here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/default.mspx

Example:

```
//putenv("LANG=esp");  <- WRONG!
putenv('LC_ALL=esp');
```

Third problem, the big one: gettext extension on windows is not thread safe. Each time you change language, the change is process wide. If you run php as fast-cgi you're ok. If you run php as apache module (for example) it's a total mess because language changes for every php instance. The problem is that gettext() relies on locale setting. This setting is process wide on windows PHP. You cannot change locale for a PHP thread but only for PHP process.

Said this, here is some working code:

```
// $MAINPATH is your document root

$locales=array(
  'it'=>'ita',
  'en'=>'eng',
  'de'=>'deu',
  'fr'=>'fra',
  'es'=>'esp',
  'ru'=>'rus'
);

$locale = $locales[$lang];
$res=putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
$rres=bindtextdomain('default', $MAINPATH.'locale');
$dres=textdomain('default');
```

locale directory structure must be the following:

```
deu
  LC_MESSAGES
    default.mo
esp
  LC_MESSAGES
    default.mo
fra
  LC_MESSAGES
    default.mo
ita
  LC_MESSAGES
    default.mo
rus
  LC_MESSAGES
    default.mo
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I haven't failed to do anything of what you say (I've omitted both `setlocale()` return value and `eng` when posting here but I've actually verified that). Thread safety is a good point but: 1) Locales won't leak from non-PHP processes, will they? 2) Does it affect the command line?

Comment: This setup is working on my box, Win7 64bit ita. 1) no, locale setting is always PHP related. 2) no, different command lines are different PHP processes and they're sealed.

Comment: I corrected examples, LC_ALL must be used and not LANG. Code below was correct.

Comment: Again, I've set `LC_ALL` by all means. (In my latest tests, the whole gettext feature appears to be broken in PHP/5.3 and PHP/5.5 but works fine in PHP/5.4. I might edit the question when I have some time.)

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu it works if you set your default LC_ALL and leave the LANG and LANGUAGE empty, like so:

```
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_ALL= "en_US.utf8"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a system variable 'LANG' with the desired locale for the value (for example 'en_US' or 'nl_NL'), restart apache and translations corresponding to that locale are shown.

[Environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqbZp.png)

This works for XAMPP with php 7.1 (thread safe) on windows 10 and locale directories structured as follows:

```
    // Directory structure
    <locale_dir>\en_US\LC_MESSAGES\bundle.po
    <locale_dir>\nl_NL\LC_MESSAGES\bundle.po
    ...
```

Answer (score -2):

You must upgrade to PHP 5.6.6 for Windows, it works!

Comment: If this was actually an issue fixed in that version of PHP, consider including some evidence (such as a changelog entry or bug tracker bug).

Comment: Are you using the official builds? I've just tried them (both x64 and x86) and it's still failing. PHP/5.4.x is the last branch that works in my current PC. :-?