# Gettext example not working on Windows 7 - XAMPP

Tags: php, localization, gettext

I have the latest XAMPP (3.2.1) with PHP 5.6.8 and gettext enabled. I'm trying to get gettext() working there using a sample I've found on the internet: https://github.com/leftnode/gettext-example , but it is not working.

Other code I've tried (translation.php):

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $textdomain = "messages";
  $lang = "de_DE";

  echo(putenv("LC_ALL=".$lang)."<br>"); // outputs 1
  setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang);
  echo(bindtextdomain($textdomain, "locale")."<br>"); // successfully outputs the correct path to locale
  textdomain($textdomain);

  echo ((function_exists("_") && function_exists("gettext"))?"gettext loaded\n<br>":""); // outputs gettext loaded

  $name = "Vic";
  printf(_("Hello, %s, it is nice to see you today.\n"), $name); // outputs original english
?>
```

translation files - compiled with Poedit 1.8.1 (messages.po)

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR Codegroove.net
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: Codegroove.net Example Translations 0.0.1\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: vmc@codegroove.net\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2015-06-01 11:34+0100\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2015-06-01 11:38+0100\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"Language: de_DE\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.8.1\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: UTF-8\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: _\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: ..\\..\\..\\\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: .\n"

#: translation.php:15
msgid "Hello, %s, it is nice to see you today.\n"
msgstr "Hallo, %s, es ist schön dich zu sehen heute.\n"
```

File locations

```
gettext\translation.php
gettext\locale\de_DE\LC_MESSAGES\messages.po
gettext\locale\de_DE\LC_MESSAGES\messages.mo
```

What else can I try to make the gettext working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that the locale is not set correctly although PHP reports it does. There is a bug in PHP that is causing this: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66265

As a result gettext always uses system default locale for translations (after creating translations with my system locale it actually works).
Related StackOverflow question: [Gettext will always use system default locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569362/gettext-will-always-use-system-default-locale)

Although the bug is closed and it should somewhat partially work I wasn't able to get it running. 
Instead I'm now using PHP solution that reads gettext .po files and that works: `php-gettext` (https://launchpad.net/php-gettext)

Comment: For me the php- gettext did not work but it helped me to find a different solution  which I explain here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62353692/gettext-doesnt-translate-my-text-properly-when-using-dutch/66088405#66088405

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the solution by setting the **`LANG`**-parameter **before** starting apache.

I open up a Command-Prompt (as administrator), next:

```
set LANG=nl_NL
xampp-control
```

Comment: that's with a  new line between 'set LANG=nl_NL' and 'xampp-control' :)

Comment: Just to add on, the XAMPP shell can be found in `C:\xampp\xampp-shell.bat` if you've installed it in the default directory. You'll also need to quit (i.e. Right-click > Quit) all existing instances of XAMPP before doing this.

I spent a couple of days troubleshooting gettext on both Windows and Ubuntu to get them working, and I've documented all the stuff that worked for me here: https://blog.terresquall.com/2020/09/troubleshooting-php-gettext/

Comment: Unfortunately nothing of this works for my xampp 64 on Windows:-(

Comment: I found a completely difernt workaround. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62353692/gettext-doesnt-translate-my-text-properly-when-using-dutch/66088405#66088405

Answer (score 0):

After afull day with nothing working I have found a proper working and simple 5 line workaround which i explain in a different post:

[GetText doesn't translate my text properly when using dutch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62353692/gettext-doesnt-translate-my-text-properly-when-using-dutch/66088405#66088405)